# Unity and Visual Studio - Issues with a button not working

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, blackjack

So I downloaded the assets file of the final version of the Sloan Kelly Card Game Project from YouTube [Link to the video where you can download it in the description](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9G3cbLGWB6g&t=0s&index=13&list=PLZo2FfoMkJeE6GXx8cEUeR9KzItTvaKlz) and I was playing around with the game it was all working fine.

I then re-opened the game the project the next day and the 'Stick Button' is no longer working. It appears on screen and appears intractable but it will not press.

I made a couple of changes to the code to make it easier to read but didn't think i had changed anything to do with this button. The rest of the code runs fine just this one button.

I'm unsure how to link my project assets package on this sight, but I can show you the code for the button and was just wondering if anyone can see the problem straight away / could you tell me how to link the whole file so you can get a better look at what is happening.

Thanks in advance

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class GameController : MonoBehaviour 
{
    int dealersFirstCard = -1;

    public CardStack player;
    public CardStack dealer;
    public CardStack deck;

    public Button hitButton;
    public Button stickButton;
    public Button playAgainButton;

    public Text winnerText;

    /*
     * Cards dealt to each player
     * First player hits/sticks/bust
     * Dealer's turn unyil minimum of 17 value in hand
     * Dealers cards: first card is hidden, other cards are facing
     */


    #region Hit

    public void Hit()
    {
        player.Push(deck.Pop());
        if (player.HandValue() > 21)
        {
            hitButton.interactable = false;
            stickButton.interactable = false;
            StartCoroutine(DealersTurn());
        }
    }
    #endregion
    #region Stick
    public void Stick()
    {
        hitButton.interactable = false;
        stickButton.interactable = false;
        StartCoroutine(DealersTurn());
    }
    #endregion
    #region Play Again
    public void PlayAgain()
    {
        playAgainButton.interactable = false;

        player.GetComponent<CardStackView>().Clear();
        dealer.GetComponent<CardStackView>().Clear();
        deck.GetComponent<CardStackView>().Clear();
        deck.CreateDeck();

        winnerText.text = "";

        hitButton.interactable = true;
        stickButton.interactable = true;

        dealersFirstCard = -1;

        StartGame();
    }

    #endregion

    void Start()
    {
        StartGame();
    }



    void StartGame()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            player.Push(deck.Pop());
            HitDealer();
        }
    }

    void HitDealer()
    {
        int card = deck.Pop();

        if (dealersFirstCard < 0)
        {
            dealersFirstCard = card;
        }

        dealer.Push(card);
        if (dealer.CardCount >= 2)
        {
            CardStackView view = dealer.GetComponent<CardStackView>();
            view.Toggle(card, true);
        }
    }
    #region Dealers turn
    IEnumerator DealersTurn()
    {
        hitButton.interactable = false;
        stickButton.interactable = false;

        CardStackView view = dealer.GetComponent<CardStackView>();
        view.Toggle(dealersFirstCard, true);
        view.ShowCards();
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);

        while (dealer.HandValue() < 17)
        {
            HitDealer();
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);
        } 

        if (player.HandValue() > 21 || (dealer.HandValue() >= player.HandValue() && dealer.HandValue() <= 21))
        {
            winnerText.text = "You Lose!";
        }
        else if (dealer.HandValue() > 21 || (player.HandValue() <= 21 && player.HandValue() > dealer.HandValue()))
        {
            winnerText.text = "You Win!";
        }
        else
        {
            winnerText.text = "The house wins!";
        }

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);
        playAgainButton.interactable = true;
    }
    #endregion

}
```

[image]

Comment: Your button becomes non interactable the moment the dealer has a turn.. After that from the code provided you never re-enable it - this should be easy to prove with debugging commands

Comment: it is re-enabled on the play again button

Comment: I cant see anything in the code provided that shows any allowance for a players second turn.. and the moment the dealers turn kicks in it disables hit and stick, nothing until a new game starts reenables them